# How to filter by posts friendship?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I currently have two tables:

**Posts table**

```
post_id     user_id     post_text     post_time
----------------------------------------------------------
1           1           TEXT          2011-10-07 19:07:00
2           2           TEXT          2011-10-07 19:10:00
3           3           TEXT          2011-10-07 19:17:00
4           4           TEXT          2011-10-07 19:23:00
5           3           TEXT          2011-10-07 19:30:00
```

**Friends Table**

```
friendship_id     friend1_id     friend2_id     status
----------------------------------------------------------
1                 1              2              1 (active friend)
2                 1              3              1 (active friend)
3                 2              3              0 (not friend)
4                 3              4              0 (not friend)
5                 1              4              1 (active friend)
```

What I am trying to do is basically **fetch all of the posts** in which **a user holds an active friend state with another user**.

**Elaborating:** User with the friend1_id of 1 has friendships with the users friend2_id 2, 3, and 4. Users with the friend2_id 2, 3, and 4 have made posts. How to fetch all of the posts that users 2, 3, and 4 have posted [since user 1 is friends with all of them]?

**Elaborating more:** If you are friends with a user [1 - active friendship] then allow the post to be fetched, else don't fetch anything if the user does not hold an active friendship.

I hope I explained myself well, else I will elaborate. Thank you.

PS: Am I missing something? Am I doing something wrong? Is there an easier way to do it? If so, please let me know. I would like to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Elaborating:**

```
Select * from Posts 
where user_id in 
(select friend2_id from Friends where friend1_id = 1)
```

**Elaborating more:**

```
Select * from Posts 
where user_id in 
(select friend2_id from Friends where friend1_id = 1 and status = 1)
```